# Why can't you use non-static late providers?

Tags: flutter, dart, dependency-injection, riverpod

We can do this:

```dart
class WorldModel {
  WorldModel({required this.skyModel});

  final SkyModel skyModel;

  static final instance = Provider<WorldModel>(
    (ref) => WorldModel(
      skyModel: SkyModel(),
    ),
  );

  final countBirds = Provider<int>((ref) => 25);
}
```

Which would mean that we can only access our `countBirds` provider after we have accessed the `WorldModel` instance. Those (in `build()` method):

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
  final worldModel = ref.watch(WorldModel.instance);
  final countBirds = ref.watch(worldModel.countBirds);
  return Text(countBirds.toString());
}
```

Otherwise, we can even define it like this:

```dart
late final countBirds = Provider<int>((ref) => 5);
```

---

It all works great and performs its **function** 100%. Even when using the `.autoDispose` modifier, everything works fine and is disposed of. *But, the official documentation strongly recommends using providers ONLY as final ones*:

> Providers should always be final.

Does this mean they can be `late`? **Why and what are the pitfalls?**

---

About **`function`**

Why do I need this (I'm talking about definitions in the `WorldModel` class)? This is because `countBirds` may depend on some fields of the `WorldModel` class. I can't do it any other way, just because I think it's *good practice for dependency injection*. Here is a good example:

```dart
class WorldModel {
  WorldModel({required this.skyModel});

  final SkyModel skyModel;

  static final instance = Provider<WorldModel>(
    (ref) => WorldModel(skyModel: SkyModel()),
  );

  late final countBirds = Provider<int>((ref) => skyModel.countBirds);
}

class SkyModel {
  late int countBirds;
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "[...] the documentation strongly recommends static providers"? The text you quote says they should be `final`, not `static`.

Comment: @offworldwelcome Thanks for the note. I rather meant that if we use providers in a class, they must be final and static (`static final`). Most of the time, this paragraph should be corrected to "...providers ONLY as final ones:" to better understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me about a year of actively practicing and testing different approaches to realize that creating providers in a way other than globally is a terrible idea.

The point is that the concept of storing states in `Riverpod` is based on an approach where the user does not need to follow the life cycle of an object. When we listen to the provider, the provider is alive. When we stop listening to it - it dies (only if we use the `autoDispose` modifier. When using a generator, you can specify a flag in the annotation). But one way or another, we don't have to affect the lives of the states because Riverpod itself takes care of that.

So **you should** only announce providers in a global way. Whether it will be a static class field or just a global scope definition is just a matter of implementation. But once you start creating providers at the local level, you're trying to take over the initiative in managing the life of the objects. This could end up in error if we lose the reference to a previously created provider that will live on, thus creating a memory leak! And I'm not talking about the possible side-effects that can be run within such a provider.

- [Creating providers locally is a bad technical decision.](https://gist.github.com/PackRuble/a07d427ab3a95a58241fab79608a2abe)

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommend to use providers as `static`, while I don't think there is technically an issue with that but still it's a bad practices.

As for defining the provider as `final` inside a class without `static` keyword, this will lead to a new provider being created with every instance of the class, so when you lose access to the class instance you will not be able to access the provider and this will be a bigger issue if the provider isn't auto-disposable.

Providers can be defined late as following

```
final myProvider = Provider<WorldModel>((ref) {
  throw UnimplementedError();
});

final countBirds = Provider<int>((ref) {
  throw UnimplementedError();
});
```

And then you can initialize the providers before accessing in the widget tree by warping the parent widget with `ProviderScope`

```
ProviderScope(
  overrides: [
    myProvider.overrideWithValue(skyModel),
    countBirds.overrideWithValue(skyModel.countBirds),
  ],
  child: const MyWidget(),
)
```

And then you can access the providers in any widget in the widget tree which is under the `ProviderScope`.

Another thing you can do is to use `.family` modifier

```
final myProvider = Provider.family<WorldModel, SkyModel>((ref, skyModel) {
  return WorldModel(skyModel: skyModel);
});
```

However you have to pass the same `SkyModel` instance to reuse the same provider instance, otherwise you will get a new provider

Comment: Thank you for your reply! You correctly noted that a provider that is in a class and is not static - must either auto-dispose (here I did not mark it as `AutoDisposeProvider`), or must dispose in the `ref.onDispose(){...});` method in the `instance` provider. But it seems obvious that a problematic situation may occur when `instance` is no longer audible and `countBirds` is still audible... Regarding `throw UnimplementedError();` - I don't like using this because of the binding to the widget tree. Although this is the true approach in all flutter.

Comment: Your answer is good, and I know that's the official approach to use. But still, what is the answer to the main question -- **Does this mean they can be `late`? Why and what are the pitfalls?**

Comment: By the way, the second approach with `.family' is more about the factory pattern. And here the story is more about lazy singleton

Comment: As for your question `can be late? what are the pitfalls?`, yes provider can be `late` however by default a provider is only initialized when it's first accessed so there is no need to use `late` at all, as a pitfall you might get is when you are trying to test with a mocked provider you wouldn't be able to override it if its `late final`.
you should use `throw UnimplementedError()` when you are trying to initialize a provider with an argument that you will have later.
what I am trying to highlight here is that you can archive same behaviour (or any thing you want) by using best practice.

Comment: I'll reward you, but it's still not a solution to my question. In any case, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Providers should always be final because non-final providers will lead to low performance.
All in all, you should make unchanging variables final because it's good modelling, not because you worry about performance. Providers should be unchanging.
Why providers should be unchanging? Because there is no reason why you may need it changing. If you need different behaviours of the provider - you can encapsulate these behaviours into the provider. If you need providers with different types you should create several final providers with different types.
You can make the provider not final but this may lead to runtime errors if you do not keep track of the type or behaviour of the provider.